# How can we convert float value to string value

Tags: stm32, stm32ldiscovery

I am trying to convert float value to string. For that i used 'ftoa' but it shows error like 'undefined reference to ftoa()'.Also i used 'gcvt()' instead of ftoa but not working.Any suggestion please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if it is good enough for you :
https://github.com/antongus/stm32tpl/blob/master/ftoa.c

Answer (score -1):

You could use sprintf. Not very efficient though.